# How to translate a delegate to absolute address in DRAM?

Tags: delegates, d, memory-address

I'd like to translate the delegate members `.ptr` and `.funcptr` to an absolute address that matches something in the executable image in DRAM.

The goal is not to call, neither to modify, but rather to allow the target to disassemble itself at run-time, when its own image is loaded in DRAM.

So far it already works with global functions.

Is it possible ?

Comment: In physical RAM or just in process memory?

Comment: You can just set the pointers to the address, using casts as needed to tell the type system you know what you're doing. ...but are you sure you know what you're doing? A delegate works in a particular way that probably doesn't match a random address. A function pointer might be more appropriate but idk just what you need to do.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: yes, in RAM

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe, since I want the absolute address in RAM I assume it's possible, it's not like if the code needed to reside in the instruction cache. I really don't care about the frame or the instance, I just want an address to the code for a class or a struct function.

Comment: oh, you already have the delegate and want the address? That's easy: `dg.funcptr` returns that without needing any other steps. You might cast to void* if you want to get rid of the type info but regardless the number is there. The absolute address in RAM won't happen because the operating system and processor is responsible for that translation, but you don't really want that anyway - you want the address in your process' space which is what the pointer gives you.

Comment: Right, just funcptr seems to work. In a previous test this failed because the disasm was clearly done on data that was not code and it never stopped. Maybe rather a bug in the disassembler kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address of a delegate is the value of the `.funcptr` property. The type of this property is a bit misleading - it is of type `function` and does *not* list the hidden argument that is actually expected for passing the context in, but for just getting the address, you can ignore the type (explicitly casting to `void*` or `size_t` if you like to change the type) and just look at the address.

This isn't the address in physical memory, you'd have to ask the operating system for that, but since the virtual address it gives is automatically translated by the processor, it is most likely what you want anyway.